# Kernel of a ring homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, quaternions, ring-homomorphism

Currently struggling with showing that the quaternions are isomorphic to a subgroup of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

I've defined a map $\phi$ from $\mathbb{R}\langle x,y,z\rangle$ to $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$, $y\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $z\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}$.

I've shown that this is a homomorphism, and that the ideal $I=(x^2+1,y^2+1,z^2+1,xyz+1)$ of $\mathbb{R}\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is contained in the kernel of $\phi $, but cannot show the other inclusion.

My method has relied on supposing that an element exists in $ker\phi\setminus I$, taking its image and trying to show that it must be multiples of $f(x)^2+1$, etc. This has not worked, and I have no idea how else to go about it.

I've had a look at some of the other questions similar to this, but they usually involve ideals with only one generator. I was wondering if there was a more simple method to showing the reverse inclusion.

Comment: You haven't fully defined the map.  Where do you send something like $3$?  Once you do that, you could let $a + bx + cy + dz$ be in the kernel, and solve some equations maybe?

Comment: These are also vector spaces.  So, you could define a linear isomorphism, and then show it respects the ring structure.

Comment: @J126 sorry, I meant that $\phi $ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism. As such, it is $\mathbb{R}$ linear.

Comment: Yes, but quaternions look like $1 + 3x + 4y - z$.  What would $\phi$ do if it were just $1$? The basis for the quaternions is $\{1, x, y, z\}$

Comment: @J126 1 maps to 1 under any homomorphism, does it not? I thought it would be obvious from context. $\phi(1)\phi(x)=\phi(1\times x)=\phi(x)=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: If you know that every element has a unique representation as $a + bx + cy + dz$, then you only need to compute when $\phi(a + bx + cy + dz) = 0$, and show that $a = b = c = d = 0$.

Comment: @J216 why does every element have a unique representation as $a+bx+cy+dz$? What about the term $(xy)^n$ for example?

Comment: The relations $x^2 + 1 = y^2 + 1 = z^2 + 1 = xyz + 1 = 0$ allow you to reduce any $(xy)^n$.  For example $xy = z$.

Comment: @J126 those relations are not true in $\mathbb{R}\langle x,y,z\rangle$. Or are you supposing I redefine the homomorphism from the quaternions instead?

Comment: You can prove directly that $\phi (a + bx + cy + dz) = \phi(a)+\phi(b)\phi(x)+\phi(c)\phi(y)+\phi(d)\phi(z)$. It looks harder than it is because the matrices form a vector space and $\phi(a)=aI$ with $I$ the identity matrix so you can treat them like scalars.

Comment: Whats your definition of quaternion? @CyclotomicField: if $\mathbb{R}<x,y,z>$ is the free $\mathbb{R}$ algebra over $\{x,y,z\}$, this follows from the universal property.

Comment: The real dimension of the subalgebra of the matrices is at least 4, since the matrices plus identity matrix are linearly independent. And the homomorphism $\phi$ from the quaternions is surjective, so since $dim_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{H} = 4$, we have that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.